# How to make a function for total product and marginal product

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, economics

In economics, there is the production function (or marginal product) function which is mathematically related to total product and it looks something like [that](https://www.toppr.com/guides/economics/production-and-costs/total-product-average-product-and-marginal-product/) (Marginal product does go to negative y). What kind of mathematical functions could represent those two economic laws?

Comment: What kind of economic laws you are referring to?

Comment: @callculus Diminishing marginal returns

Comment: The Cobb-Douglas function has diminishing marginal output: $y=x_1^{\alpha}\cdot x_2^{\beta}$, where $0<\alpha,\beta <1$ The partial derivative is $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_1}=\alpha\cdot x_1^{\alpha-1}\cdot x_2^{\beta}$, where $\alpha-1<0$